# I want to extract POS tags from a tagged sentence

Tags: tags, extract

s="[('you', 'PRP'), ('move', 'VBP'), ('on', 'IN')]"

I want the output as
(PRP,VBP,IN)

Please hlp

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct then s is a list containing tuples. You can make a for loop that goes through the list and takes out each POS tag:

```
pos_list = []
for token in s:
    pos_list.append(token[1])

print pos_list
```